# wso2 api mgr: oauth not working

Tags: api, oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager

after install of wso2 mgr and a small change in the jdbi to use our mysql server everything "seems" to work except oauth.

In carbon web UI, when i click on the left menu on "oauth"  i get an error message saying

```
System Error Occurred - Error occurred while reading OAuth application data
```

I looked at other post and [saw this](http://blog.thilinamb.com/2012/08/configuring-oauth-20-access-token-store.html). i looked at `${WSO2_IS_HOME}/repository/conf/identity.xml` where i saw  that i had an entry  `<skipdbschemacreation>true</skipdbschemacreation>`

I try to change it to false and no change...

Anybody had this problem with wso2 apu mgr ?

Any idea how to setup oauth in api mgr ?

Do i have to install wso2 identity manager ?

----update1 ------

it seems that changing to false this flag is creating a problem with our db as we get now an error message. When you reset this flag to true, the db error is still there ...

the error message says

[2012-08-19 15:40:13,649] ERROR - JDBCResourceDAO Failed to delete the resource with id 688. Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

and later the wso2 launch script said :

[2012-08-19 15:40:13,654] FATAL - CarbonServerManager WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to delete the resource with id 688. Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

little bit later in the same launch script we have

org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

Answer (score 1):

The ***skipdbschemacreation*** property was specifically introduced after the introduction of the WSO2 APIManager. This was because the WSO2 APIManager has a seperate sql script to create all the required tables (including the OAuth2.0 related tables). Therefore it was necessary to skip the schema creation step of the OAuth component on server startup. Thus it is correct that this property is set to *'true'* by default in the WSO2 APIManager and to *false* in WSO2 Identity Server.

The problem you are facing should be because your configurations that point to your MySQL database are incorrect. If you are using a MySQL database, the place where you should configure its settings is **{WSO2_APIMANAGER_HOME}/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml**. Change the setting of the datasource whose name is WSO2AM_DB. This is the datasource which has the OAuth2.0 related tables.

E.g.

```
        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2am_db</url>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin@123</password>
                    <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

I presume you've already created the required database schema by running the mysql.sql script provided in **{WSO2_APIMANAGER_HOME}/dbscripts/apimgt/mysql.sql**.

To create a MySQL database schema for WSO2 APIManager:

1. Navigate to the location where you have the mysql script for creating the WSO2AM_DB.
2. Open a command prompt from that location and login to mysql from cmd prompt

   mysql -u root -p
3. Create a database. Create user and grant access.

   create database apimgt;
4. `GRANT ALL ON apimgt.* TO admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "admin";`
5. Run the mysql.sql script. This will configure the database.

   use apimgt;

   source mysql.sql;

Comment: issue is now close. all came from the fact that on carbon webUI the oauth was not working. I discovered that in the {WSO2_APIMANAGER_HOME}/repository/apimgt/mysql.sql. you have a subdir named apimgr that contain a second mysql.sql script ... As soon as i runned it all missing idn_* table had been created and everything seems to work as of now... maybe you could launch this second script automatically or write somewhere it is require to run it ? Thanks anyway for your support....